# invalidpropertyexception and indexoutofboundsexception while submitting form in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am facing the following exception while submitting form in spring mvc.

**org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException**

**nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0**

I have a list **studentList** in my FormBean class.
When control is passed from Controller to JSP, I am displaying records from this list in JSP.

Things are working fine till this.

Now, when i try to submit the form again. I am getting the above mentioned exception.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give enough information. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or carefully read it again if you only quickly looked at it.

Comment: You need to post your code for JSP and Controller setup before assistance can be provided

Comment: @User0206 Have you intialized the list from controller, or somehow your model attribute or commanName is getting messed up.

Comment: Yes, the list has been initialized in the Controller. And the commandName in <form:form> and @ModelAttribute in Controller method are same.